# How to stop Wordpress from saving custom post types to wp_posts

Tags: database, wordpress, content-management-system, custom-post-type

I want to have a custom table in the database called 'Products'. The user will be able to add/edit/delete products using the back end interface. All updates and changes will be made to this 'Products' table. I tried doing this in Wordpress using custom post types. I created a 'Product' custom post type and then a plugin to detect when a post is published. However, custom post types will automatically save all posts to the database wp_posts, which is not what I want. In doing this, i will be having duplicate information.

Is there a way to stop wordpress from saving this to wp_posts? Or is it not advisable, which in other words means Wordpress isn't the right CMS for what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: naturally its not how wordpress behaves.. you are not using the core feature of WP so it will be better to use someother CMS like YII, CI..

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what are YII and CI

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/ YII

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter ci

Comment: http://fatfreeframework.com/home

Comment: So is there a way to stop Wordpress Save Custom Post types into the Wordpress Table or not ? The Codex at least says that there is a way to use custom tables